# Action of discrete subgroup of Lie Groups

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, lie-groups, topological-groups

Given $\Gamma$ a discrete subgroup of a lie group $G$ I want to show that the action is wandering:

$\forall x\in G\exists U_x\vert \{\gamma\in\Gamma\vert \gamma U_x\cap U_x\neq \emptyset\}$ is finite

By considering a neighbourhood of the identity $V$ such that $V=V^{-1}=V^2$ and $V\cap \Gamma= e$ I have showed that every orbit $\Gamma y$ intersects $Vx$ in at most one element and then I got stuck any ulterior hints would be appreciated.

Comment: It would probably be useful if you included the definition of «wandering» in the body of your question.

Comment: It is nough to check that condition for $x=e$, as everything is invariant under translation. Then $U$ needs to be picked so that it is an open set such that its intersection with $\Gamma$ is just $\{e\}$, and such a thing exists because $\Gamma$ is discrete.